# NodeJS forever after @reboot

Tags: node.js, nginx, forever

I am working with React and need my web page to be alive after reboot.
So I need forever after crontab.

What I have tried.

```
crontab -e

@reboot ~/reboot.sh
@reboot sudo service nginx restart
```

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/lacirolnikdev && sudo ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.1/bin/forever start -c "/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.1/bin/npm start" .
cd ~/coinwork && sudo ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.1/bin/forever start -c "/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.1/bin/npm start" .
```

I tried absolute paths, sudo and moving to directories.
Commands works fine besides crontab.

Thank you Laci

Comment: look into pm2, even they suggest it. then it's as simple as running `pm2 startup` once. btw you shouldn't run your app as root

Answer (score 0):

A better way to start processes after boot would be a `systemd` unit file, the de-facto standard init daemon on most distributions. `systemd` takes care of starting your application, is capable of monitoring and restarting it on crashes.

Have a look at the documentation for unit files here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

This is an example for `nginx`:

`/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Documentation=man:nginx(8)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I don't have start-stop-daemon in AWS distribution which is key to ExecStop in this case.